# 'Popen' object not Iterable

Tags: python, linux, list, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to fetch some Ids into a list via the subprocess command. Below is my code:

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
list1 = subprocess.Popen("pgrep -u root",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
for i in list1:
    file1 = open(os.path.join('/proc',i,'status')).readlines()
    for line in file1:
        if line.startswith("Mem: "):
             id = int(line.split()[5])
        if line.startswith("Cpu: "):
             toC = int(line.split()[8])
list2 = (id,toC)
for k in list2:
    self.text.insert(INSERT,k[0])
    self.text.insert(INSERT,k[1])
```

The error that i get is: 'Popen'object not iterable.
I am creating a list and fetching the IDs into a list and then for every ID in the list, I am trying to get the mem and cpu information. this information is again input into another empty list(list2). I am iterating over list2 to display these information. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: a portable way to get the processes info is to [use `psutil` module](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil#summary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the result of the call you'll need to [communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) with the 
subprocess object

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-u', 'root'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
text = proc.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')

for i in text.splitlines():
    ...
```

The `Popen` object is not the output of the process, it is an object that represents the running subprocess.

Also avoid `shell=True` if you can as it is widely considered a security concern, and you don't need it here.

Comment: I get this error: TypeError("Can't mix strings and bytes in path components.") when i try to iterate it your way..

Comment: @dee yes that is a different issue but I've updated the line to decode

Comment: Why does it say, "No such file or directory  pgrep -u root". When i try to print, it just works fine though.

Comment: what do you mean by "when I try to **print** it"? Also what line is that error coming from?

Comment: @ RyanHaining : When i use a print statement like : print(list2.communicate()) it works fine i.e it prints all the PIDs handled by this user (root, in my case) .

The error is from line 1 (filenotfound error from subprocess.py)

Comment: @Dee `list2.communicate` doesn't make sense because `list2` is a tuple. I suspect you didn't copy the code correctly, if all you did was take out the `shell=True` but didn't replace the process you are calling with a list you will get that error. this is wrong: `subprocess.Popen('pgrep -u root', stdout=subprocess.Pipe)`, this is right: `subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-u', 'root'], stdout=subprocess.Pipe)` as it is in my answer

Comment: @ RyanHaining: Thanks, I wasn't using the quotes properly though had made all the changes you mentioned above. This does clear the existing error, but throws a new one : "id referenced before assignment". It seems to me like it is not entering my for loop where 'Id' is calculated.. Any comments on why this is happening?

Comment: None of the lines in the files start with "Mem: "? You can look at it with the shell to confirm `sudo cat /proc/1/status | grep "Mem: "` for example.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario (where you're only reading `stdout` and `stdin`/`stderr` are untouched), you probably don't want `.communicate` or `.run`. It's easier to process the lines as they're produced, which those APIs don't do (they buffer everything into memory before returning).

To process the output line by line, just change:

```
for i in list1:
```

to:

```
for i in list1.stdout:
```

In addition, you've got a problem with types on Python 3; to fix that (and avoid the problems with `shell=True`) change the `Popen` line to:

```
list1 = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-u', 'root'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

where `universal_newlines=True` makes reads from `list1.stdout` return `str`, not `bytes`.

Comment: Note: If you're piping two of the standard handles independently, you cannot safely read/write any of them without the use of `select`/`selectors` primitives or threads; it's only because you're using exactly one standard handle that deadlock on full pipes isn't an issue.

Comment: Note: `universal_newlines` has been renamed to `text` in more recent versions of Python.

Comment: @DaVince: Well, aliased. They don't appear to be planning to deprecate it, so you *can* use both, and you'd need the longer name if your code needs to run on 3.6 or earlier, but yes, `text=True` is much shorter and clearer (the `universal_newlines` name is an artifact of the Python 2 days, when all it did was enable newline conversions).

Answer (score 0):

Calling `subprocess.Popen` yields a [Popen object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).  It does not give you a list and it does not give you something you can iterate over, because the `Popen` object is not iterable.

It is easier to use a higher level function from the same library to get the output as a string, then parse this and loop accordingly.  In Python 3.5, you can simply call [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
res = subprocess.run(["pgrep", "-u", "root"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which will give you a `CompletedProcess` object from where you can inspect the output.

In Python 3.4 or earlier, you can instead use [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Comment: I am using python 3.4 and it says : Attribute Error: Module object has no attribute run.

Comment: @Dee `subprocess.run` is new in Python 3.5.  See edit.